# Doctrine search simple_array field that has matching keywords

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have entity that has simple_array field `keywords`. For example I have entities with values `drama, adventure, action`, and the other `drama, sci-fi`.
I want to provide `action, adventure`, and returned first entity. Because it has matching keywords.

If I try searching with IN array, it works only if entity keyword field has only one entry.

```
$query->andWhere("g.keyword IN (:keywords)")
    ->setParameter('keywords', $keywords);
```

My question is, how should a query look like, to be able to search by multiple keywords, while field has multiple keywords.

Comment: So in the Database they stored as serialized string. Like `"a:3:{i:0;s:5:"drama";i:1;s:9:"adventure";i:2;s:6:"action";}"` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your prop declared like this:

```php
/**
* 
* @ORM\Column(name="keyword", type="simple_array")
*/
private $keyword;
```

There is no easy way.
`simple_array` just auto-serialize your php-array data into a serialized string every time you save/update (INSERT/UPDATE) it to database *and* auto-deserialize it from serialized-string to a php-array each time you read (SELECT)

As long as I know, there's **no solution** for that **with MySQL** and doctrine.
However, PostgreSQL has some neat features for storing serialized data, but I'm not sure.

The only thing I could imagine is to use LIKE for each single keyword you provide. So if you provide `action, adventure` SQL would be

```sql
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE keyword LIKE '%action%' AND keyword LIKE '%adveture%'
```

to get this with doctrine (QueryBuilder)

```php
foreach($keywords as $idx => $singleKeyword) {
   // note, that you have to put '%' at the start and at the end and use it as param
   // LIKE %:keyword% -> would not work. 
   $query->andWhere('g.keyword LIKE :keyword_'.$idx)->setParameter('keyword_'.$idx, '%'.$singleKeyword.'%' );
}
```

But you'll get results only if all provided keywords match.

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right, I did something similar but uglier, my DQL looks like
`AND (g.keyword LIKE '%adventure%' OR g.keyword LIKE '%action%')`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know on what you working, but if possible, change you DB-Structure. Make a separate table for you keywords in the way that in this table every record stand for one keyword and has a reference to you main Entity.

If do it like this, is much easier to work and build query with it.

```
SELECT * FROM MainEntity LEFT JOIN Keywords ON Keywords.MainEntityId = MainEntity.Id
WHERE Keywords.Value IN (Value1, Value2, Value3)
```